# possible mongodb driver bug?

Tags: mongodb

I was playing around with mongodb on PHP and I noticed something strange, look at these:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f08958fd80aa8cf6d000000"), "nickname" : "alex" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f089669d80aa8cd6d000000"), "nickname" : "franz" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f0896b3aaca83b3c256b6b4"), "nickname" : "sergej" }
```

notice the _id, in the first two the last 6 numbers, which should be randomly generated, are all zeroes, those two are the ones I created on a php page, the last one I created directly from mongo interface.

Now, I know the id is already unique enough but on production this is going to be a problem, do you know if this is a bug or maybe there's a workaround this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only a random number if an incremented value will not work.

See the BSON ObjectID Specification section:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

Comment: I read that, and apparently the random number is not working either, I created quite a few objects and they all have those zeroes there.

Comment: It's because you're not creating them at the same time. The time part changes, so it has no need to increment the counter at the end.